# Setting a max value for string to binary conversion

Tags: java, binary

I'm trying to convert the binary string `1111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` (as sign magnitude 32 bit number) to an `int` where the answer should be `-2147483648` it is returning `-1073741822`. Is there a way to adapt a min and max value when converting the string to an int so as to get the right answer?

```
public static int binaryStringToInt(String s) {
        int result = 0;
        boolean negative = false;
        int i = 0, 
        max = s.length();
        int radix = 2;
        int digit;
        // int maxLimit = 2147483647 ?
        // int minLimit = -2147483648 ?

        if (s.charAt(0) == '1') {
            negative = true;
            i++;
        }

        if (i < max) {
            digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(i++),radix);
            result = -digit;
        }

        while (i < max) {
            digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(i++),radix);
            result *= radix;
            result -= digit;
        }

        if (negative) return result;
        return -result;

    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: get the binary string representation of Integer.MAX

Comment: As a clue... the answer you're getting is almost exactly half of what it should be.

Comment: The binary representation of `-2147483648` is `1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000` so I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: by the way, this method can be simplified to: `return Integer.parseInt(s, 2)`

Comment: @ajb That is the representation of `-0` as sign-magnitude number - which is the system I'm working in. Or at least that is the answer I am getting.

Comment: @Cruncher I am trying to create my own implementation of that method. Thank you though! I found this here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.toBinaryString%28int%29  but am coming up short. It may have to do with the sign magnitude format?

Comment: Ah, I see... I missed the "sign magnitude" in the question because I didn't think anyone actually ever used it.  However, your question shows us a string with 31 1's in it, not 32, which was also confusing--was that a typo?  ... Actually, how can you represent `-2147483648` at all?  I'd think that if `-0` is a possibility, then your actual range should be -(2^31-1) to +(2^31-1), with two ways to represent zero, but no way to represent -2^31.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Do calculations in long
long maxLimitMagnitude = 2147483647L;
long minLimitMagnitude = 2147483648L;
long magnitude         = 0L;

// Decide first if number is positive or negative
boolean negative = (s.charAt(0)=='1' ? true : false);

// Accumulate magnitude from left to right starting with second digit
for (int i=1; i<s.length(); i++)
{
    magnitude<<= 1;      // or *= radix for the general case (radix other than 2)
    magnitude+= Character.digit(s.charAt(i), radix);
}

// make sure the magnitude will fit in a 2s complement int
if (magnitude> (negative ? minLimitMagnitude : maxLimitMagnitude))
    throw new ArithmeticOverflowException(); // your own exception class

return (int)(negative ? -magnitude : magnitude);
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! So for overflow as you're trying to catch would it be fair to say something like `if magnitude > minLimitMagnitude  return -minLimitMagnitude} else { return maxLimitmagnitude }`. If you were to say that wherever overflow occurs it is only the upper or lower bound?

Answer (score -1):

In the `binaryStringToInt()` I needed to change from

```
if (s.charAt(0) == '1') {
    negative = true;
    i++;
}
```

to

```
if (s.charAt(0) == '1') {
    negative = true;
    // i++; - was not counting the first char as part of the number
}
```